# ar_track_alvar: no (rgb) camera tracking in bundle detection using kinect?

Tags: ros, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running bundledetection (using FindMarkerBundles.cpp) with kinect, the actual tag tracking seems to be based only on the kinect data, as in individual detection (using IndividualMarkers.cpp) the tracking is based on the camera data, and improved by the kinect data.

This can be tested by blocking the kinect ir projector, the tag in the individual case remains detected, although with some jitter. In the bundle case the detection stops, also nearby detection (<50cm) is not possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74104/ar_track_alvar:-no-(rgb)-camera-tracking-in-bundle-detection-using-kinect?/) by [swarmlab](https://answers.ros.org/users/6076/swarmlab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the source of FindMarkerBundles.cpp shows, that the node creates a  [camera subscriber object](https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/blob/groovy-devel/nodes/FindMarkerBundles.cpp#L86) but the node never subscribes to a camera topic.
So, it does not use camera information.

I'm pretty happy with FindMarkerBundlesNoKinect. Does work great for me.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20167/amine/) on 2014-09-19**:
Hello,
I am trying to track a bundle with kinect using FindMarkerBundles, but I get errors ERROR InferCorners: "camera_1_rgb_optical_frame" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.". However same parameters work very good with the individualMarkers code.
You have any idea?